# Pandoc greek letters not rendering

Tags: html, markdown, pandoc

I am trying to convert a .md to HTML with pandoc.

The markdown contains a `$\Iota$` and pandoc is not converting it:

```
[WARNING] Could not convert TeX math \Iota, rendering as TeX:
  \Iota
       ^
  unexpected control sequence \Iota
  expecting "%", "\\label", "\\tag", "\\nonumber" or whitespace
```

The pandoc command:

```
 pandoc .\Input.md -f  markdown -o Output.html --template='templates pandoc\elegant_bootstrap_menu.html'   --toc --standalone
```

How can I fix this?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `\Iota` is not defined by default. Add

```tex
\def\Iota{I}
```

to the document somewhere before the first equation that uses `\Iota`. This will cause pandoc to replace all instances of `\Iota` in equations with `I`.

You might also want to use a non-default option for math rendering. See the section [Math rendering in HTML](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL#math-rendering-in-html) in the manual.

Comment: Thanks, I tried all the options until --katex worked :)